# error when use Sql Navigator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-navigator

I have error when using tool Sql Navigator 6.2.1:
I run command in Sql Navigator it alert error: "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 140
ORA-06512: at line 6"

```
desc com.zsdddept;
```

com.zsdddept is table
and when i run select command its no error and click table name show properties of table in Sql Navigator no action.

But i run above command in Oracle Sql developer (same user) result no error and show description fields.

What's the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `desc` command is not a SQL standard. `desc` is the sqlplus command.
SQL Developer runs a big sql query and sql navigator a simple sql query.
SQL Navigator® for Oracle Version 6.2.1 does not support ORACLE version 11.2.

SQL Navigator® for Oracle Version 6.2.1 Release Notes Release Notes September 2009.

Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1) 2 April 2010

You need to buy and install the latest version of SQL Navigator or use the free version of sqlplus or Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Navigator performs its custom SQL emulation of the SQL * Plus command.
SQL Developer your own custom SQL emulates the SQL * Plus command.
Grant the right to execute the SYS.DBMS_UTILITY package.

```
grant execute on SYS.DBMS_UTILITY to <username>;
```

Example 1  `desc DEPT` run in SQLNavigator 6.7

```
select /*+ ALL_ROWS */ column_name,data_type,nullable,data_length,NVL(data_precision,-99),NVL(data_scale,-99),char_used, char_length 
 from sys.all_tab_columns where owner='SCOTT' and table_name='DEPT' order by column_id

Name                           Data Type                     
------------------------------ ------------------------------
DEPTNO                         NUMBER(2,0)           NOT NULL
DNAME                          VARCHAR2(14 BYTE)
LOC                            VARCHAR2(13 BYTE)
```

Example 2  `desc DEPT` run in SQL Developer v4.1

```
select t.column_name "Name", 
                            decode(t.nullable,'Y',null,'NOT NULL') "Null",
                            decode(t.data_type_mod, null, '', t.data_type_mod ||' OF ')|| 
                            (CASE WHEN ( t.data_type_owner = UPPER(t.owner) OR t.data_type_owner is NULL )
                                  THEN ''
                                  ELSE t.data_type_owner ||'.' 
                             END ) || 
                            UPPER(t.data_type)||  
                            case when (   t.data_type='VARCHAR' 
                                       OR t.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' 
                                       OR t.data_type ='RAW' 
                                       OR t.data_type='CHAR') AND (
                                       t.data_length <> 0 AND 
                                       nvl(t.data_length,-1) <> -1)        then 
                                       case when(t.char_used ='C' and 'BYTE' =(select value from nls_session_parameters where PARAMETER='NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS')) then '(' || t.char_length || ' CHAR)'
                                            when(t.char_used ='B' and 'CHAR' =(select value from nls_session_parameters where PARAMETER='NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS')) then '(' || t.data_length || ' BYTE)'
                                            when(t.char_used ='C' and 'CHAR' =(select value from nls_session_parameters where PARAMETER='NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS')) then '(' || t.char_length || ')'
                                            when(t.char_used ='B' and 'BYTE' =(select value from nls_session_parameters where PARAMETER='NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS')) then '(' || t.data_length || ')'
                                            else '(' || t.data_length || ' BYTE)' 
                                       end    
                                 when (t.data_type='NVARCHAR2' OR t.data_type='NCHAR') then  
                                 '(' || t.data_length/2 || ')'   
                                 when (t.data_type like 'TIMESTAMP%' OR t.data_type like 'INTERVAL DAY%' OR t.data_type like 'INTERVAL YEAR%' OR t.data_type = 'DATE' OR
                                  (t.data_type = 'NUMBER' AND ((t.data_precision = 0) OR NVL (t.data_precision,-1) = -1) AND  nvl (t.data_scale,-1) = -1)) then
                                  '' 
                                 when ((t.data_type = 'NUMBER' AND NVL (t.data_precision,-1) = -1) AND (t.data_scale = 0)) then
                                  '(38)' 
                                 when ((t.data_type = 'NUMBER' AND NVL (t.data_precision,-1) = -1) AND (nvl (t.data_scale,-1) != -1)) then
                                  '(38,'|| t.data_scale ||')' 
                                 when ( t.data_type='BINARY_FLOAT' or t.data_type='BINARY_DOUBLE'   ) then
                                    ''
                                when (t.data_precision is NULL AND t.data_scale IS NULL ) then 
                                ''
                                when (t.data_scale  = 0 OR nvl(t.data_scale,-1) = -1) then
                                  '('|| t.data_precision ||')'
                                when (t.data_precision  != 0 AND t.data_scale  != 0 ) then
                                    '('|| t.data_precision ||',' ||t.data_scale ||')'     
                            end "Type"   
                            from sys.all_tab_columns t, sys.all_col_comments c
                             where t.column_name = c.column_name and c.owner = t.owner and c.table_name = t.table_name and
                              UPPER(t.owner) = UPPER(sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER')) and t.table_name = :2 order by t.column_id


Name   Null     Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
DEPTNO NOT NULL NUMBER(2)    
DNAME           VARCHAR2(14) 
LOC             VARCHAR2(13)
```

In the sql cache, this is the procedure call.

```
 declare
       l_schema      varchar2(128);
       l_part1       varchar2(128);
       l_part2       varchar2(128);
       l_dblink      varchar2(128);
       l_part1_type  number;
       l_objid       number;
    begin
     DBMS_UTILITY.NAME_RESOLVE ( 
       name          => :obj_name, 
       context       => 2,  -- interested in dba_ views only; 0 doesn't work in 10g -- bug 19528375
       schema        => l_schema,  
       part1         => l_part1, 
       part2         => l_part2,
       dblink        => l_dblink, 
       part1_type    => l_part1_type, 
       object_number => l_objid );
    end;
```

inv_restricted_object exception;
  pragma exception_init(inv_restricted_object, -24239);

comment on line 140 when handling an exception in SYS.DBMS_UTILITY

```
 /*
   * Option flags supported by invalidate.
   *   inv_error_on_restrictions - The invalidate routine imposes various
   *   restrictions on the objects that can be invalidated. For example,
   *   the object specified by p_object_id cannot be a table. By default,
   *   invalidate quietly returns on these conditions (and does not raise
   *   an exception). If the caller sets this flag, the exception
   *   inv_restricted_object is raised.
   */
  inv_error_on_restrictions constant pls_integer := 1;
```

Comment: Why is the grant on `dbms_utility` needed? The first query doesn't use that.

Comment: What is object type `com.zsdddept` ? This sql for table only.

Comment: com.zsdddept is table

Comment: `declare
   l_schema      varchar2(128);
   l_part1       varchar2(128);
   l_part2       varchar2(128);
   l_dblink      varchar2(128);
   l_part1_type  number;
   l_objid       number;
begin
 DBMS_UTILITY.NAME_RESOLVE ( 
   name          => :obj_name, 
   context       => 2,  -- interested in dba_ views only; 0 doesn't work in 10g -- bug 19528375
   schema        => l_schema,  
   part1         => l_part1, 
   part2         => l_part2,
   dblink        => l_dblink, 
   part1_type    => l_part1_type, 
   object_number => l_objid );
end;`

Comment: I run command grant execute on SYS.DBMS_UTILITY to <username>; but i get same error. I don't understand

Comment: what is version database?

Comment: Run this SQL `select * from all_objects where object_name = upper('zsdddept');`

Comment: Oracle version 11g

Comment: COM ZSDDDEPT  107392 107392 TABLE 22-Aug-2017 14:10:58 24-Aug-2017 16:38:48 2017-08-22:14:10:58 VALID N N N 1

Comment: SQL Navigator 6.2.1 supports Oracle clients 8i through 11g. not 11gR2 [Release Note 6.2.1](http://www.toadsoft.com/sqlnavigator/ReleaseNotes/6_2_1/SQLNavigator_6.2.1_ReleaseNotes.htm)

Comment: select * from v$version

Comment: SQL Navigator® for Oracle
Version 6.2.1 Release Notes
Release NotesSeptember 2009

Comment: Oracle Database  11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1)  2 April 2010

Comment: You need to buy and install the latest version of SQLNavigator or use the free version of sql * plus

Comment: i installed SQLNavigator 7.1 and not got error above, thanks!